# .htaccess Redirect rule to another domain

Tags: .htaccess

Currently I can rewrite a URL like this

`RewriteRule ^pageOne$ /pageOne.php`

I would like to do a Redirect to another domain not a rewrite to the current

So in the example below users who click on pageOne get redirected to the other URL

`RewriteRule ^www.example.com/pageOne$ www.newexample.com/pageOne.php`

EDITED

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.example.co.uk$
    RewriteRule ^a-blog-post$ http://www.newexample.com/reviced-blog-post.html [L,R=301,NC]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    # END WordPress
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That rule will be like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^pageOne/?$ http://www.newexample.com/pageOne.php [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Is there a simpler way without the `?` etc so it's URL to URL eg direct from `www.example.com/blog-post-one` to `www.newexample.com/revised-blog-post-one`. I am doing this with old blog posts to new blog posts so i need to replicate this rule 200+ times

Comment: Yes rather than writing that many rewrite rule should be avoided using regex. If you tell me few real examples of your old page named then I can suggest something better.

Comment: OK thanks. Here is an example OLD `www.example.com/a-common-blog-post` NEW `www.newexample.com/2013/a-different-title-same-content`

Comment: Hmm if old page name and new page name look entirely different as per your example: `a-common-blog-post` vs `a-different-title-same-content` then I think regex won't help. You can use RewriteMap feature of Apache mod_rewrite.

Comment: I think for simplicity I will just duplicate the redirect rules per blog post. Based loosely on your example Would this work `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com/a-common-blog-post [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newexample.com/2013/a-different-title-same-content$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: No it has to be `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$` since `%{HTTP_HOST}` can only match host name. You can have URI in RewriteRule then like `RewriteRule ^a-common-blog-post$ http://newexample.com/2013/a-different-title-same-content [L,R=301,NC]`

Comment: I just tried this `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.example.co.uk$  
RewriteRule ^a-blog-post$ http://www.newexample.com/reviced-blog-post.html [L,R=301,NC]`  and got a 500 error *The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.*

Comment: Can you post you latest .htaccess in your question please, difficult to see code syntax from comments.

Comment: Appears to be alright, just make sure there is no stray space anywhere in these 2 lines.

Comment: I've added in my other .htaccess lines in case you think there is a conflict?

Comment: Yes there will be a conflict. Move these lines before WP stuff, just below `RewriteBase` line.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and i get the same error. Updated my answer with what i tried.

Comment: Ok, Can you tail your apache error.log and see what error you're getting there.

Comment: There must be an issue as I have uploaded the old .htaccess file without my edits and now i'm still getting an error.

Comment: Yes as I said your new rules look fine, just tail your apache error.log and see what error you're getting there.

Comment: Well my `.htaccess` file is not causing an error but also it is not redirectiing

Comment: Finally worked. Your code worked perfectly the error was with the redirectBase that had been previously set. Many thanks for your help throughout.